# Obtener varbinary(50) de SQL Server a byte[] en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, visual-studio-2010

Estoy realizando un `Login`, en el cual la clave del usuario almacenada en la Base de datos es de tipo `varbinary(50)` debo recuperar este valor, para posteriormente compararlo con la clave `string` digitada por el usuario.

En la Base de datos tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> password = `0x61646D696E` en `string` es `admin` utilizando el `Encoding.ASCII`.

He realizado lo siguiente (asuma que la conexión `cnn` esta abierta):

```
string comando = string.Empty;
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

byte[] claveByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt_clave.Text.Trim());
string claveString = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(claveByte).Replace("-", string.Empty);

comando = @"select nombre_usuario, convert(varchar(50), password, 1) as clave from USUARIO 
            where nombre_usuario = '" + txt_usuario.Text.Trim() + "'" +
            " and password =" + claveString;

using (SqlDataAdapter sentencia = new SqlDataAdapter(comando, cnn))
{
       sentencia.Fill(dataset);
       sentencia.Dispose();
}

byte[] claveObtenida = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["clave"].ToString());
usuario = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nombre_usuario"].ToString();
clave = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(claveObtenida);

if (txt_usuario.Text == usuario && txt_clave.Text == clave)
{
    //.........
    //........
}
```

> `txt_usuario.Text = "admin";` y `txt_clave.Text = "admin";` , al momento de convertir a `string` la clave obtenida de la base de datos obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Hay una mejor forma de hacerlo sin implicar el uso de tantas conversiones de tipos y poder comprar correctamente la clave del usuario?**

Entordo: Visual Studio 2010 (WindowsForms) C#, .NET NetFrameWork 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas cosas que pudes mejorar en tu código.

Primero, usa parámetros en tu consulta, sino vas a estar expuesto a SQL injection

```
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = @"
select nombre_usuario, convert(varchar(50), password, 1) as clave 
from USUARIO 
where nombre_usuario = @usuario and password = @password";
```

Segundo, si tu campo es un binary, compara binaries con binaries no tienes necesidad de convertir:

```
byte[] claveByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt_clave.Text.Trim());
command.Parameters.Add("@password", claveByte);
```

Tercero, que el password este en binary no significa que sea seguro, yo ahora sé que estás almacenando simplemente el ASCII encodeado, puedo robar tu base de datos (no lo voy a hacer :p) y puedo desencodearlo.

Te recomiendo investigar y usar algo como [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=RNGCryptoServiceProvider&oq=RNGCryptoServiceProvider&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.208j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Tu código podría ser así:

```
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = @"
select nombre_usuario, convert(varchar(50), password, 1) as clave 
from USUARIO 
where nombre_usuario = @usuario and password = @password";

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@usuario", txt_usuario.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt_clave.Text.Trim())));

if(command.ExecuteScalar() == null)
{
    return "Bad Password";
}
else
{
    return "Good Password";
}
```

Comment: Aquí solo veo mejorado la parte de los parámetros, pero en que momento asigno los valores obtenido a las  variables `usuario` y `clave` para posteriormente comprar aquí: `if (txt_usuario.Text == usuario && txt_clave.Text == clave)` ? y `var command = new SqlCommand();` **No contiene una definición para hacer: `command.Text`** en dado casi sería : `command.CommandText`

Comment: Son ejemplos, podes seguir a partir de aquí.

Comment: En tu lugar no compararía nada, puede ejecutar un `ExecuteScalar`, si no obtienes nada es porque el password no matcheó y si obtienes el nombre significa que el password es válido

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@password"

Comment: Agregaste el `command.Parameters.Add("@password", claveByte);`

Comment: Claro, esta agregado, pero igual me dice que debo declarar la variable escalar `password` , modifica tu respuesta, como debo ejecutarla tomando en cuenta esto `using (SqlDataAdapter sentencia = new SqlDataAdapter(comando, cnn))
{ ...}` o como debe ser?  donde debo usar ` command.ExecuteScalar();` ?

Comment: Ahí creé un código de ejemplo, obviamente no tengo tu base para probarlo.

Comment: Listo!, una observación el VS salta dice que `Parameters.Add` esta obsoleto, por lo tanto lo recomendable es `Parameters.AddWithValue` Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Voy a tratar complementar un poco la respuesta de @hardkoded. Para el manejo de los password para el login que deseas implementar no te recomiendo utilizar un proceso para encriptar y desencriptar la clave, mi recomendación sería utilizar una función hash criptográfica. Esta función hash siempre te va a retornar el mismo resultado para el valor que ingreses, si ingresas otro valor va a generar un resultado completamente diferente al anterior. Te dejo enlace con las funciones hash disponibles en .net. No utilices MD5 ni SHA1 ya que no son muy seguros y no se recomiendo seguir utilizandolas, puedes utilizar SHA256, SHA384, SHA512.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx

Pseudocódigo de como funcionaría esto:

Primer caso Insertar Nuevo usuario:

```
  1- Lees usuario y password ingresado por el usuario.
  2- Hash = FuncionHashCriptografica(password) //obtienes el hash del password
  3- Insertas en BD Usuario y Hash obtenido en el paso anterior.
```

Segundo caso iniciar sesión:

```
 1- Lees usuario y password ingresado por el usuario.
 2- Hash = FuncionHashCriptografica(password) //obtienes el hash del password
 3- BuscarUsuarioEnBD(usuario, Hash)
 4- Si retorno un usuario procedes con iniciar sesión
 5- Si no retorno un usuario puede significar dos cosas. O el usuario no existe o que el password ingresado no es el correcto.
```

Como puedes observar en el segundo caso para iniciar sesión la comparación de las claves se hace en función del hash generado a partir del texto que ingreso el usuario en el campo del password, lo que esta en BD no se desencripta.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias!